# Changing color of HTML element using radio button

Tags: javascript

I have 10 groups of radio button with two options, each group separated by a `<div>`.

```
<div id = "radio1">
    <p>Do you like to walk?</p>
    <input type="radio" value="a" name="radgrp1"/> Yes <br />
    <input type="radio" value="b" name="radgrp1"/> No <br /> 
</div>

<div id = "radio2">
    <p>Would you prefer to walk without effort?</p>
    <input type="radio" value="a" name="radgrp2"/> Yes <br />
    <input type="radio" value="b" name="radgrp2"/> No <br /> 
</div>
```

Then I have 10  tags that point to each group.

```
 <a id ="a1" href="#radio1">Goto 1</a>
 <a id ="a1" href="#radio2">Goto 2</a>
```

What I am looking to achieve is the moment a user clicks on "Yes" option, color of respective  tag ie Goto 1, Goto 2 etc turns green.

Comment: On a side note I would like to walk without effort.

Comment: In that case, you might like to walk on a bus.

Comment: I've noticed you've mentioned IE6 a couple times. First, my condolences. Second, WHYYYYYY. Third, your best bet is to either (1) Drop that functionality on IE6 or (2) Actually take a look at why it's breaking in IE6 and debug it yourself. I don't know anybody who is willing (or even able) to test on IE6 right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may [try this](http://jsfiddle.net/8Y2xe/1/) (assumed there is no `document.body.onclick` event handler other than this)

```
var radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[name^=radgrp]');
document.body.onclick = function(e){
    var evt = e || window.event, target = evt.target || evt.srcElement;
    if(target.name) {
        var prefix = target.name.substr(0, 6), suffix = target.name.substr(6);
        if(prefix && prefix == 'radgrp') {
            if(target.value == 'a' ) {
                document.getElementById('a' + suffix).style.color = 'green';
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById('a' + suffix).style.color = '';
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Put this code just before the closing `</body>` tag between `<script>` tags like

```
<script type='text/javascript'> // code goes here </script>
```

Also, you may [check this](http://javascript.info/tutorial/onload-ondomcontentloaded) for registering events using different approaches.

**Update :**

`querySelectorAll` won't work in `IE-6` so you may try [this alternative solution](http://jsfiddle.net/8Y2xe/4/) for `IE-6` to work. Also, if you use [jQuery](http://jquery.com) (put the code in `<head>` between `<script>`), you may use [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/8Y2xe/5/) and in case of `jQuery`, you have to add `jQuery` script in your `<head>` section section first.

Comment: Thanks it worked but not in IE6, and I need to make it work in Internet Explorer 6. Is there a workaround to make it work in IE 6, :D thanks

Comment: This is the best answer so far.

Answer (score 2):

A common technique is to create a relationship between elements by using data attributes. In your case, you could put an attribute on each input/radio button that references the id of the element you want to affect.

```
<input type="radio" value="a" name="radgrp1" data-target="a1" /> Yes <br />
```

Then using some jQuery you could do this:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('data-target');
    $('#' + id).css('background-color', 'rgb(255, 255, 255)');
});
```

Comment: Usually unless it's tagged as jQuery, you'll be downvoted for posting a jQuery answer.

Comment: Will it work in IE6, wud u pls you show a small example. thanks.

Comment: @RUJordan while I _usually_ hate to see jQuery answers needlessly - in this case when OP has to support IE6 - jQuery makes sense :/